Measure Chlorogenic Acid Levels Using High School Equipment
I'm currently working on a high school project studying the effects of increased temperature during roasting on the chlorogenic acid levels in coffee.
I am finding trouble in quantitatively measuring this. From the literature I have seen it seems that it is most common to use UV-Vis spectrometer of 290 nm wavelength. My school does not have this equipment and only have spectrophotometers measuring higher wavelengths.
Other methods seem to use even more expensive equipment such as chromatography machines and such.
I am wondering if there is a method of measuring the chlorogenic acid levels another way that does not involve expensive equipment and can be done in a standard high school lab.

You could use a colorimeter. They are often cheaper than Uv vis spectrometers.

Hi I have searched it up online and there doesn't seem to be a method using a colorimeter

The principle of the colorimeter is the same, if you are applying beer's law. For a chosen wavelength it will give you an absorbance value, instead of giving an entire spectrum, like what you would expect from Uv-Vis spectrophotometer.

So would a colorimeter be able to measure low wavelength range of the chlorogenic acid?

I am sure you have a supervising chemistry teacher. Can he/she also guide you for the resources, perhaps in a college or a university connection? You are right, chlorogenic acid is indeed easily analyzed by HPLCs. Whenever we design experiments, we first check the resources. This would be good lesson in project management.

Chlorogenic acid(s) are fluorescent. Search how to extract it with the help of your teacher. Your lab should have a UV lamp, you can try to take pictures and use ImageJ software to calculate the intensities. This will give you some idea, how the fluorescence is changing.

Or maybe oxidise it - as the name says it gets green i.e. absorbs in vis. range.

No, oxidation to green color is from its dimers not monomers. Read this article: Chlorogenic Acid Oxidation and Its Reaction with Sunflower Proteins to Form Green-Colored Complexes.
